# finding the kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{8 \times 4}, x \in \mathbb{R}^4$

$Qx = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
-2 & 0 & -1 & 1\\ 
0 & -2 & 0 & -2\\ 
2 & -2 & 1 & -3\\ 
0 & 4 & 0 & 4\\ 
-2 & 6 & -1 & 7\\ 
0 & -8 & 0 & -8
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c\\ 
d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Matrix $Q$ has rank=2 , and $rank(Q)+dim(Ker(Q))=4$

If I solve the system (with Gaussian elimination), I get the solution $S=\{(\alpha,0,2\alpha,0)|\alpha \in \mathbb{R}  \}$

Is the solution wrong? if $dim(Ker(Q))=2$ , then the solutinon should have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

EDIT: It was an error in the Gaussian elimination

$S=\{(\alpha,\beta,-2\alpha,-\beta)|\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}  \}$

Comment: You should have $(1,0,-2,0)$ and $(0,1,-1,-1)$ as a base to the nullspace.

Comment: Thank you! how did you find the base?

Comment: If $\operatorname{rk} Q = 2$, then there are two linearly independent rows. Pick two linearly independent rows and figure out their null space.

Comment: @Cristi: you made a mistake in your gaussian elimination I think, your method was correct.

Comment: @Cristi You may answer your own question and accept it (i.e. click the "tick" symbol on the left of the answer), so that it no longer appears in the "unanswered" queue. This helps the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is $S=\{(\alpha,\beta,-2\alpha,-\beta)|\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}  \}$

Comment: No! The solution is $\{(\alpha,\beta,-2\alpha-\beta,-\beta) : \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\}$